# Can I set both (in and out) charsets in `less`?

Tags: character-encoding, less

I can tell `less` to output characters in UTF-8:

```
export LESSCHARSET=UTF-8
```

But then it tries to read files as UTF-8 as well.

Can I tell it to read files as ISO-8859-2 (latin2) but display them as UTF-8 like I do in `vim` with `enc` and `fenc` settings?

Comment: You could write a preprocessor (passed via LESSOPEN) based on iconv, maybe?

Comment: How would that look like? AFAIU I'd loose the ability of less to display streamed data as soon as it gets it, wouldn't I? I would have to wait for the preprocessor to finish converting the file?

Comment: For you last two questions, I think so. How would that look like? You should be able to figure it out from the "INPUT PREPROCESSOR" section of the manpage. I'd use two custom variables in the script, like IN_ENC and OUT_ENC, to be able to call e.g. `IN_ENC=latin2 OUT_ENC=utf8 less my_file`. Tell me if you want more help I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: I guess the only valid answer to my question is "no" because there seem to be no way of making `less` convert characters "on the fly". Your suggestion is the best we have then. Please, write an answer and I'll mark it. I'll ask another question regarding the same issue but with streaming data as I have to read and search 1GB+ log files remotely.

Comment: pipe through `iconv -i latin2 -o utf-8`. If you hate the extra buffering, look into `stfbuf.`

Comment: @Cyprian: thanks for the offer. @Arthur2e5: the correct switches are `-f` and `-t`, respectively.

Comment: @L.Levrel Ugh… You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible.
As a partial workaround, you may use `iconv` as an input preprocessor in the following way.

1. Create the following executable script, say `less_conv.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   iconv -f $IN_ENC -t $OUT_ENC $1
   ```
2. Define and export the `LESSOPEN` variable:

   ```
   export LESSOPEN="|-less_conv.sh %s"
   ```
3. Invoke `less` this way:

   ```
   IN_ENC=latin2 OUT_ENC=utf8 less somefile
   ```

   You may also set your preferred values:

   ```
   export IN_ENC=latin2
   export OUT_ENC=utf8
   less somefile
   ```

The pipe character `|` in `LESSOPEN` saves the need for a temporary intermediate file. The dash `-` enables this preprocessor when `less` reads standard input.

Limitation:
The preprocessor is invoked only once, even if you hit `F` or `R`, so you won't be able to use this workaround on growing files or "streaming" standard input.